# chunksize for time dimension is not working with xr.open_mfdataset

Tags: dask, python-xarray

Using xr.open_mfdataset, I wish to chunk in the time dimension; however, the chunksize for 'time' remain equal to 1 despite setting it equal to 12. Chunking for 'lon' and 'lat' work though. How can I chunk in the 'time' dimension? Thanks- PG

```
VARS_USED = ["LANDFRAC", "PSL", "PRECC", "PRECL", "TREFHT", "ICEFRAC", "PRECSL_H218OS", "PRECSC_H218Os", "PRECRL_H218OR", "PRECRC_H218Or", "PRECSL_H2OS", "PRECSC_H2Os", "PRECRL_H2OR", "PRECRC_H2Or"]

WSOL_DATA_PATH = '/glade/p/ncgd0030/Steig/90_WSOL/b.ie12.BG1850C5CN.f19_g16.90_WSOL.001_daily.cam.h0.000[2-4]-??_avg_fc.nc'

WSOL_DATA = xr.open_mfdataset(WSOL_DATA_PATH, decode_cf=False, chunks={'time':12, 'lon':72,'lat':48})[VARS_USED]
```

OUTPUT:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:        (lat: 96, lon: 144, time: 36)
Coordinates:
* lon            (lon) float64 0.0 2.5 5.0 7.5 10.0 12.5 15.0 17.5 20.0   ...
* time           (time) float64 380.0 409.5 439.0 469.5 500.0 530.5 561.0 ...
* lat            (lat) float64 -90.0 -88.11 -86.21 -84.32 -82.42 -80.53 ...
Data variables:
LANDFRAC       (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(36, 96, 144), chunksize=(1, 48, 72)>
PSL            (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(36, 96, 144), chunksize=(1, 48, 72)>
PRECC          (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(36, 96, 144), chunksize=(1, 48, 72)>
PRECL          (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(36, 96, 144), chunksize=(1, 48, 72)>
TREFHT         (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(36, 96, 144), chunksize=(1, 48, 72)>
ICEFRAC        (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(36, 96, 144), chunksize=(1, 48, 72)>
PRECSL_H218OS  (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(36, 96, 144), chunksize=(1, 48, 72)>
PRECSC_H218Os  (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(36, 96, 144), chunksize=(1, 48, 72)>
PRECRL_H218OR  (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(36, 96, 144), chunksize=(1, 48, 72)>
PRECRC_H218Or  (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(36, 96, 144), chunksize=(1, 48, 72)>
PRECSL_H2OS    (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(36, 96, 144), chunksize=(1, 48, 72)>
PRECSC_H2Os    (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(36, 96, 144), chunksize=(1, 48, 72)>
PRECRL_H2OR    (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(36, 96, 144), chunksize=(1, 48, 72)>
PRECRC_H2Or    (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(36, 96, 144), chunksize=(1, 48, 72)>
Attributes:
Conventions:               CF-1.0
source:                    CAM
```

Comment: Do you have one time-point per input file?

Answer (score 1):

`chunks` in `open_mfdataset` currently only chunks *within* each input file. If each file contains only one time point, then setting a larger chunk size won't have any effect.

If you want larger chunks along the time dimension, you need to add a separate `.chunk()` call afterwards. E.g.

```
WSOL_DATA = WSOL_DATA.chunk({'time': 12})
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards rechunk. Could you expand on how to add the .rechunk() call afterwards?  I tried iterations of WSOL_DATA.rechunk(), but WSOL_DATA is a "Dataset and has no attribute 'rechunk'".  I also tried rechunking a data variable, WSOL_DATA.data_vars['PSL'].rechunk(), but this does not work because "DataArray has no attribute 'rechunk'".

Comment: Oops, fixed. The method is actually called `chunk`